# Returning a hex code color given a number between 0 and 1

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I would like to create a heatmap that goes from green to red. The closer to 0 the more green, the closer to 1 the more red. I know its possible with RGB colors using matplotlib. How is this done with Hex Color Codes?

Any hints or nudges in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `red, green = int(255*x), int(255*(1-x))`, and then convert to hex: `f"#{red:02x}{green:02x}00"`

Comment: It isn't really clear why not just using RGB colors, or even better, an existing colormap?

Comment: The package I am using for plotting only support hex colors...

Comment: The more details there are, e.g. about the package in question and the expected outcome, the better the answers.

Comment: http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/docs-v0.5.0/modules.html, the circle marker takes in a hex code as color value

Comment: So the very first comment here is what your looking for, right?

Comment: Yes! that does just what I need!